# Performance of an "almost sequential" primary key in MySQL (InnoDB index)

Tags: mysql, innodb

I understand than an InnoDB primary key index is far more performant when the records are sequential than when they are random.

However, I'm curious about the performance of the InnoDB primary index for values that are *almost* sequential. Say I'm not using `auto_increment`, but instead some application-side sequential UUID scheme that is stored as BINARY(16), as described in [this excellent article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/12/19/store-uuid-optimized-way/).

If the records are almost-but-not-quite sequential, what does this mean for storage and query performance?

Comment: Why is an InnoDB primary key index far more performant when the records are sequential than when they are random?

Comment: That would only apply while inserting.

Answer (score 1):

"Count the disk hits".

Case 1:  All the data and index fits in the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.
The ordering of the rows and/or index does not matter much.  (There are no disk hits, except when finally persisting everything to disk.)

Case 2:  The data and/or index is too big to fit in the buffer_pool.

Case 2a:  The data/index is sequential, or nearly sequential, or has a limited number of "hot spots".
There will be one or a 'limited number of' blocks that are getting all the activity. These (presumably) easily fit in the buffer_pool.  So, there is no performance problem.

Case 2b:  The data/index is random (eg, UUID or MD5).
Now, since the data/index is too big to fit, and the inserts are randomly jumping around, there will be a lot of I/O to get the job done.  I/O is the performance killer.  (Since the block to contain the 'next' UUID is unlikely to be cached in the buffer_pool, it will need to be read, modified and eventually written back to disk.)

The data (in InnoDB) is sorted by the `PRIMARY KEY` in one BTree.  Each 'secondary' index is in its own BTree.

Now let's break up the problem a different way...

Case 1.  You have only a PK, no secondary keys.
If it is easy to sort the data by the PK before loading, this makes the load run fast.  (Fill a block, write to disk; repeat.  Can't get fewer disk hits.)

Case 2.  You have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` PK, plus a secondary key.
In this case, if you pre-sort by the secondary key and let the `AUTO_INCREMENT` do its thing, it will run fast.

Case 3:  If you have two keys (PK and/or secondary) that have different characteristics, such as a timestamp and a UUID, then
You are stuck.  You may try to pre-sort by one to optimize it, but, the other will be random and slow.  (Being efficient on one index, inefficient on the other.)

Back to your question.  "Almost sequential" probably implies that you are not hitting many different blocks.  For example, if you have a year's worth of data, and the PK is a timestamp, but the data for each day is jumbled, then that is "almost sorted".  At any time, you are jumping around in only a day's worth, not all year.

Answer (score 0):

You can find detailed and useful information about InnoDB index in this interesting article by Jeremy Cole

http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/the-physical-structure-of-records-in-innodb/

Anyawy do the fact the indexes are base on a  B+Tree index structures what you affirm

> the records are almost-but-not-quite sequential

don't change the performance because  firts the sequential aspect is not realeted to the meaning of the field  (1,2,3 instead of 1,5,7) but on the "distribution" of the value. In this case the two scenario you show are the same  in term of distribution of value ..